# What's the different between | and || in this case

Tags: javascript, notation

What's the difference between these two line of code?

```
number = window.number|5;
```

vs

```
number = window.number||5;
```

They both work as intended, but I am unsure the exact meaning of | vs || in these cases. Is there a chance that one would failed over the other?

The idea is to go like this when I am unsure if the page has loaded jQuery or not.

```
window.jQuery = window.jQuery|loadJquery();
```

Comment: They don't function the same - try `number = window.location | 5;`. Plus even if they did, why would you prefer a non-popular notation? To save a character?

Comment: Oh. I just figure out myself. number = 5|5; is a lot different than number = 5||5;

Comment: no kidding relational vs bitwise who would've thought they where different